# Linkedin Marketing API - what is Google_UID in matched audience

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to implement Linkedin marketing api, and while going through this link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/linkedin/marketing/integrations/matched-audiences/create-and-manage-segment-users

the API accepts userids as Google_UID, I'm wondering where to find the Google_UID? Any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have already see this? https://gist.github.com/msafi/b1cb05bfab5b897c57e6

Comment: Yes, there's no option for user-id anymore with Google. I was wondering if they are actually referring to https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#uid this in Google Analytics.